# Haskell cant pass variables

Tags: haskell

I'm very much a beginner at Haskell and I've hit a rather annoying bump in the road. At my current stage I am just trying to pass a lists from my main function into another and just PRINT it and I don't understand why it wont work.

In my head, I feel like I should just be able to:

```
    main = do
          putStrLn "-----Text Editor-----" 
          putStrLn "Please enter your text"
          leftString <- getLine
          putStrLn $ "\n\n" ++ leftString ++ "|" 

    moveCursorLeft = do
          putStr $ leftString
```

but this doesn't seem to work as 'leftString' is not in scope.

Comment: Very few languages should be able to do that.  When you get to writing more complicated programs, you'll see why it's useful.

Comment: The languages which *can* do that (e.g. Lisp and shell) use *dynamic* scoping, rather than the more common *static* or *lexical* scoping.

Answer (score 5):

Function calls are a handshake between caller and callee: the caller must pass some arguments, and the callee must accept them. As you've written it, `moveCursorLeft` doesn't accept any arguments. But don't worry, it's easy to fix:

```
    moveCursorLeft leftString = do
        putStr $ leftString
```

You could now use this in `main`, e.g.

```
    main = do
        leftString <- getLine
        putStr "\n\n"
        moveCursorLeft leftString
        putStrLn "|"
```

Comment: moveCursorLeft is to be called by a user to move the 'cursor' through the text that has been input into leftString

e.g. "A,B,C,D" | "E,F,G" => moveCursorLeft => "A,B,C" | "D,E,F,G"

Comment: That seems like a different question. It isn't good to amend or expand questions through comments.

Comment: @BasicBooties: You would want to separate your data model from the way it's printed, and your program logic (like moving a cursor) from printing logic, e.g. `moveCursorLeft ("ABCD", "EF")` ~> `("ABC", "DEF")`. And then print the cursor afterwards, `printCursor ("ABC", "DEF")` ~> *printing* `A, B, C | D, E, F`.